# Ошибка при обращении к таблице по её названию

Tags: c#, sql, oledb

```
using (OleDbDataAdapter adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM [Table1$]", conStr.ConnectionString))
{
      adapter.Fill(dataSet);
      dataSet.Tables[0].TableName = "MyTable1";
}

using (OleDbDataAdapter adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM [Table2$]", conStr.ConnectionString))
{
      adapter.Fill(dataSet);
      dataSet.Tables[1].TableName = "MyTable2";
}

dataSet.Relations.Add("MyTable1_MyTable2", dataSet.Tables["MyTable1"].Columns["SomeColumn"], dataSet.Tables["MyTable2"].Columns["SomeColumn_REF"], true);
```

В этом случае всё работает, никакой ошибки не возникает.

```
using (OleDbDataAdapter adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM [Table1$]", conStr.ConnectionString))
{
      adapter.TableMappings.Add("Table", "MyTable1");
      adapter.Fill(dataSet);          
}

using (OleDbDataAdapter adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM [Table2$]", conStr.ConnectionString))
{
      adapter.TableMappings.Add("Table1", "MyTable2");
      adapter.Fill(dataSet);          
}

dataSet.Relations.Add("MyTable1_MyTable2", dataSet.Tables["MyTable1"].Columns["SomeColumn"], dataSet.Tables["MyTable2"].Columns["SomeColumn_REF"], true);
```

В этом случае на последней строчке возникает ошибка "Ссылка на объект не указывает на экземпляр объекта."
Если эта часть строчки обрабатывается нормально `dataSet.Relations.Add("MyTable1_MyTable2", dataSet.Tables["MyTable1"].Columns["SomeColumn"],`, то дальше к "MyTable2" с помощью индексатора обращаться не хочет, возникает вышеупомянутая ошибка. Если в блоке using для второй таблицы создать строчку `dataSet.Tables[1].TableName = "MyTable2";`, то всё будет работать нормально.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

По умолчанию извлекаемые таблицы именуются адаптером как *Table*, *Table1*, *Table2* и т.д. У вас создаётся новый адаптер для заполнения каждой из таблиц, соответственно каждый раз имя по умолчанию начинается с *Table*.

Т.е. ваш код сработает, если во втором случае заменить

```
adapter.TableMappings.Add("Table1", "MyTable2");
```

на

```
adapter.TableMappings.Add("Table", "MyTable2");
```

Вы также можете использовать адаптер для заполнения `DataTable` отдельно от `DataSet`, после чего добавить эти таблицы и связь между ними в `DataSet`:

```
DataSet dataSet = new DataSet();

DataTable dataTable1 = new DataTable("MyTable1");
using (var adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM [Table1$]", conStr.ConnectionString))
    adapter.Fill(dataTable1);

DataTable dataTable2 = new DataTable("MyTable2");
using (var adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM [Table2$]", conStr.ConnectionString))
    adapter.Fill(dataTable2);

dataSet.Tables.Add(dataTable1);
dataSet.Tables.Add(dataTable2);

dataSet.Relations.Add(
    "MyTable1_MyTable2",
    dataTable1.Columns["SomeColumn"],
    dataTable2.Columns["SomeColumn_REF"],
    true);
```